# Rails 5 - limit selection of associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app that I am building to learn RoR, I have Annotation (for documents of a document type) with tags (much like posts and comments). When adding a tag to an annotation, I want to limited the possible types of the tag to those tag types that have the same document type as the document type of the annotation.

To reduce the list of tag types I already use a scope to get active tag types. Like so:

```
<%= f.association :documenttype, :collection => Documenttype.active.order(:name) %>
```

with this scope

```
scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
```

How can I extend it for matching document types? If with a scope, how; if not, what approach should I take then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: add more filters on `:collection` like so...

```
<%= f.association :tagtype, prompt: 'Select tag type', label: false, :collection => Tagtype.active.order(:name).where(:documenttype => @annotation.documenttype_id) %>
```